# WinSCP won't execute the entire script specified on a command-line

Tags: winscp

My very first post but before coming here I did a research on the issues I have.  Mostly on WinSCP forums but it came to no fruition.

Using `winscp.com`, I would like a script to use `get` command to download multiple files using SFTP.  Here is my version:

```
echo ENTER WEEK NUMBER

set /p input=""

cls

Rem Create folder based on date

set year=%date:~6,4%


mkdir \\11.111.111.11\Folder1\"Folder 2"\#Folder3\%year%_WK%input%

mkdir \\11.111.111.11\Folder1\"Folder 2"\#Folder3\%year%_WK%input%\User_1

mkdir \\11.111.111.11\Folder1\"Folder 2"\#Folder3\%year%_WK%input%\User_2

mkdir \\11.111.111.11\Folder1\"Folder 2"\#Folder3\%year%_WK%input%\User_3

c:

cd Program Files (x86)

cd Winscp

WinSCP.com /command ^

        "#echo off" ^

        "# Connect to server"^

        "Open sftp://Uname:pass@999.999.999.999" ^

        "# batch off mode" ^

        "option batch off" ^

        "lcd \\11.111.111.11\Folder1\""Folder 2""\#BFolder3\%year%_WK%input%\User_3" ^

        "cd .."^

        "cd RemoteFolder/USer_Folder" ^

        "get %year%WK%input%.zip"^

        "cd .."^ 

        "cd User_2_Folder" ^

        "get User2WK%input%.csv"^

        "get SAV_LACWK%input%.csv"^
```

Issue is, the WinSCP executes `cd ..`  after the first `get` command and it just stops.  It won't go any further:

[image]

If I copy/paste at the command prompt, it works fine.

Any idea?

Thank you
Donne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All your absolute local paths use a wrong syntax `C\:` for a drive. The correct syntax is `C:\`.

   ```
   mkdir C\:%year%Folder\
   mkdir C\:%year%Folder\Data_User
   ...

   WinSCP.com /command ^
       ....
       "lcd C\:%year%Folder\Data_User" ^
   ```
2. You are missing a quote and an escape character (`^`) after

   ```
       “# Change remote directory
   ```
3. You are using fancy quotes (`“` and `”`), instead of the plain double-quotes (`"`) in:

   ```
       “#Set local directory”^
       ....
       “# Change remote directory
   ```
4. You have a space after the `^` in

   ```
   "cd .."^
   ```

   This effectively makes the `^` be ignored (it escapes the space, not the newline).

See WinSCP FAQ [Why are some scripting commands specified on WinSCP command-line in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

---

*If this does not help, we need to see the output of the batch file run (ideally with removed `@echo off`).*

Comment: The edited code resembles more the original code I am having the issue with.  Please note that I altered sensitive information such folder names, ip addresses etc....  As Martin suggested, I tried to include the output of the batch but it seems I do not have enough point to or privilege to do so.

Comment: + You have a space after the `^` in `"cd .."^`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have a space after the ^ in "cd .."^.  The batch file now runs as intended.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing both the double quote and ^ at the end of the line before

change this:

```
“# Change remote directory
```

to:

```
"# Change remote directory" ^
```

Comment: Thanks AleFranz. I have already tried that and still it doesn't work.  It exists at exactly the same line.